# I have an error message with " i18n_data-0.8.0 " and Bundle install command doesn't launch anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I m trying to re-launch on project on Rails.
After rails s (or any command) 
I have this error 
"Could not find i18n_data-0.8.0 in any of the sources"

ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin15]
Bundler version 1.17.3

I tried this : gem install i18n -v 0.8.0 (it doesn't work).

I dont remember the check list when you re-start a clone project...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're attempting to install the wrong gem. If the error message is stating the missing gem is `i18n_data`, and not `i18n`, then the command would be:

```
gem install i18n_data -v 0.8.0
```